# float arrays in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Do I need to null-terminate a basic float array in objective C?

I have a basic float array:

```
float data[] = {0.5, 0.1, 1};
```

and when I do a sizeof(data) I get "12".

Comment: In what context will you use it? If the function that will be supplied this array requires that it be null-terminated, then yes. If it doesn't require, you don't have to.

Comment: Hi, I loop through it in a regular for loop so and I plot those points on a graph. Do I need to null terminate then in the declaration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to null terminate it to create one, no. And in general a method taking a `float[]` would also take a size parameter to indicate how many elements there are.

You get `sizeof(data) = 12` because a `float` is 4-bytes on your architecture and there's 3 of them.

Comment: so I need to use another function to get the number of elements in order to get 3 instead of 12 to set up my for loop? 

 for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(data) - 1; i++)

Comment: `count = sizeof(data) / sizeof(float)`. Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Using_sizeof_with_arrays

Comment: @Ayrad -- There is no standard, reliable way to get the number of elements in a C array.  You can do `sizeof(array) / sizeof(element)` for arrays with a declared size, but it doesn't work for dynamically allocated arrays, or arrays passed as a parameter.  (And if the array has a declared size there's no point in doing the computation in the first place -- just use the declared size.)

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` return the amount of memory (in bytes) occupied by the parameter. In your case, every `float` occupies 4 bytes, thus 4*3=12.

As Hot Licks said in the comment of mattjgalloway's answer, there is not a standard way to retrieve the number of elements in a C array.

Using `size = sizeof(data) / sizeof(float)` works, but you must be careful in using this approach, since if you pass the array as a parameter it won't work.
A common approach is to store the size in a variable and use it as upper bound in your for loop (often functions that expect an array have an additional parameter to get the size of the array).

Using a null-terminated array is useful because you can iterate through your array and stop when the `i`-esim element is null (that's the approach of methods like `strcmp`).

Answer (score 1):

Values of type `float` can never be null, so it's not possible to terminate an array of type `float` with null. For one thing, variables of any primitive type always have a numeric value, and the various null constants (in Objective-C `nil`, `Nil`, NULL, and `'\0'`) have the literal value `0`, which is obviously a valid value in range of a `float`.

So even if you can compile the following line without a warning,

```
 float x = NULL;
```

...it would have the same consequence as this:

```
float x = 0;
```

Inserting a null constant in an array of type `float` would be indistinguishable from inserting `0.0` or any other constant zero value.